# How to use a SurfaceView from an Adapter (Android)

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have a GridView.  I would like each item to be an object derived form SurfaceView.  I have created a class which extends SurfaceView, and an Adapter whose getView() returns an instance of this.

All I get is a little black square for each grid item.  The SurfaceView's draw() is never called (shown by adding trace) and neither is its surfaceCreated().

How do I do this in a way which allows me to draw stuff on the SurfaceView please?  I think the crux of the problem is that surfaceCreated() is never called.  Why not?

This is my Adapter:

```
public class LevelAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LevelNumberView number = new LevelNumberView(m_context);
        number.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        number.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        number.masDraw();   // Experiment - but it doesn't work
        return number;
    }
```

}

Then my SurfaceView class:

```
public class LevelNumberView extends SurfaceView
                             implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        m_surfaceHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Log.i("LevelNumberView","Draw");
        doDraw(canvas, Color.YELLOW);
    }

    public void masDraw()
    {
        Log.i("LevelNumberView","masDraw");
        if (null != m_surfaceHolder)
        {
            Canvas canvas = m_surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (null != canvas)
            {
                doDraw(canvas, Color.GREEN);

                m_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas, int colour)
    {
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        int min = Math.min(w,h);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(colour);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawCircle(w/2, h/2, min, paint);
    }
}
```

Thanks!
-Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `draw()` probably isn't what you want.  If you want to draw on the View, override `onDraw()`.  If you want to draw on the Surface, that's usually done from a separate thread.  (The SurfaceView has two parts; the surface part is a completely separate layer that is drawn behind the layer with the View-based UI.)

If you haven't called `SurfaceHolder().addCallback()`, no object will be receiving callbacks -- the SurfaceView doesn't send callbacks to itself, so subclassing SurfaceView doesn't really do much for you.

Perhaps what you want is simply a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks.  Lots of stuff there, not quite sure where to go with it...onDraw() isn't called either.  I can get the SurfaceHolder by calling getHolder(), and drawing works from a separate thread (using a Hander), but if I switch away from the app and back again, we're back to a black square.  How can I cause it to get (re)drawn at the correct times (other than by doing it over and over, unnecessarily) please?

Comment: The Activity and SurfaceView lifecycles are loosely coupled.  An explanation and recommendations can be found here: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity .  My guess is you didn't store the SurfaceHolder in a static and it got lost, and you didn't get a new one because the Surface didn't get recreated.  As far as the View goes, `onDraw()` is only called when the View is invalidated and requires rendering; if you were trying to drive a custom View from a game loop you would issue the invalidate manually.

Comment: A good solution (from your answer) seems to be to subclass View, not SurfaceView.  I did that, then overrode Draw() to do the necessary drawing, and it works a treat in every circumstance I have tried.

Comment: I think that's what you want.  As an added bonus, Canvas rendering to a custom View can be hardware-accelerated, whereas Canvas rendering to a SurfaceView surface is always done in software.  I updated the answer with a link to the custom view docs (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).